# How to resolve DataImportHandler Exception

Tags: solr

I am trying to import data from SQL server using DIH.I am getting below exception.

```
null:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:399)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInstance(SolrCore.java:420)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createRequestHandler(SolrCore.java:477)
at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers.initHandlersFromConfig(RequestHandlers.java:154)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:577)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:504)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:816)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:510)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:333)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:282)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:101)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:277)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:382)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4638)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5294)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:649)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1585)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please help me to resolve this and tell me is there any other way to index data into solr without using DataImportHandler or Is there any way to index data to solr using any C# app or something like that ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `apache-solr-dataimporthandler-x.y.z`.jar and `apache-solr-dataimporthandler-extras-x.y.z.jar` files into the **lib** folder in Solr home and configure lib directory in `solrconfig.xml` file.

Another way to index data is to use [SolrSharp](http://solrsharp.codeplex.com/) project.